# OpenShift deployment with Jenkins fails

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I have an jenkins job that builds and deploys to a tomcat7 instance on OpenShift

Tomcat7 cartridge is copied from http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/github/worldline/openshift-cartridge-tomcat

```
....
....
Starting tomcat cartridge
Timed out waiting for http listening port
Error deploying to gear
```

The last command on the build is

```
gear remotedeploy --deployment-datetime $deployment_dir
```

So when this job runs, it always fails, however tailing the server logs shows deployment goes fine and application is deployed successfully. Seems to me the jenkins job waiting tomcat startup but *never* receives a signal. Therefore "Timed out waiting for http listening port" and job thinks deployment failed and so job fails.

Is there anything that I can do to fix this? May be inside build script? Or make remote deploy not to expect an signal?

Please advise, thanks.

Updating this ticket(10/13/2014);
I see a difference in the console output between this failing job and a successful job. below excerpt is always on the *successful* job (which is deploying to jbossews) and failing job (which is deploying to the aforementioned cartridge) doesn't have that part at all!
I thought this could be an important difference. See below console output;

```
+ hot_deploy_enabled_for_latest_deployment
++ ruby_sdk latest_deployment_metadata.hot_deploy
++ oo-ruby -I/usr/lib/openshift/cartridge_sdk -rruby/sdk -e 'include OpenShift::CartridgeSdk; puts latest_deployment_metadata.hot_deploy'
+ enabled=
+ '[' '' == true ']'
+ return 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be worth logging an issue with the person who built the cartridge here https://github.com/worldline/openshift-cartridge-tomcat, or you could try using one of the standard jbossews (which is tomcat) cartridges that openshift offers.  Seems that all they did for this cartridge was rename everything that said "jbossews" to "tomcat".  OpenShift offers tomcat 6, tomcat7, jboss as 7, jboss eap, and wildfly cartridges, I am sure one of those would work equally as well, and work correctly with jenkins also.

Comment: I tried with jbossews and it works without any problems. So asking the cartridge creator seems like a good idea. The reason I chose this cartridge and not choosing jbossews is, jbossews has tomcat version 7.0.40 which misses the CORS plugin, starting from 7.0.41 CORS plugin is embedded in Tomcat.

Comment: Does Jboss AS 7 or WildFly have what you need?

Comment: I ended up using jbossews-2.0, in which they have upgraded Tomcat to v7.54. So the problem solved that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the worldline-openshift-origin-release-4, it may fix your issue : http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/github/worldline/openshift-cartridge-tomcat?commit=worldline-openshift-origin-release-4

Comment: Can you take a look at my latest update on this? At the bottom marked 10/13/2014. It might be why this cartridge is failing because it doesn't execute that part? Just a thought...